# How to run timer and while loop at the same time (using turtle graphics in Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, timer, turtle-graphics

I made a game, and it runs in a while loop using turtle graphics. I am trying to implement a timer that shows how much time is left until the game ends. I made the timer successfully, but I do not know where to place it in the code. If I put the timer before the loop, the program never gets to the loop. If I put it after the loop then the program never gets to the timer. If I put it in the loop then the loop cannot loop again until the timer is finished.

Comment: You'll need to run the loop or timer on a different thread. At minimum, we'd need to see the code to help you beyond that, but this would likely be too broad. Look up how to use threads, give it a try, then post back when you have something specific that we can help you with.